# How to send token with magento2 SOAP wsdl Request

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2, wsdl

How to invoke soap wsdl request for magento2 in SOAPUI.

I have created a soap wsdl request in SOAPUI using my URL `http://192.168.0.1/Magento2/soap/default?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1`.
 When i invoke request its giving error `Consumer is not authorized to access %resources`. To overcome this i have found another request `http://192.168.0.183/M2EE/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1` which is giving token.

But how to send token in customerrepository request.

**Customer Save Request**
`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://192.168.0.1/M2EE/soap/default?services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <def:customerCustomerRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
         <customer>

            <email>pprasad@gmail.com</email>
            <firstname>prasad</firstname>
            <lastname>p</lastname>
         </customer>
      </def:customerCustomerRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

**Customer Save Response**
`<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:m="http%3A%2F%2F192.168.0.1%2FM2EE%2Fsoap%2Fdefault%3Fservices%3DcustomerCustomerRepositoryV1%26wsdl%3D1">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">`***Consumer is not authorized to access %resources***`</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
         <env:Detail>
            <m:GenericFault>
               <m:Parameters>
                  <m:GenericFaultParameter>
                     <m:key>resources</m:key>
                     <m:value>Magento_Customer::manage, self</m:value>
                  </m:GenericFaultParameter>
               </m:Parameters>
            </m:GenericFault>
         </env:Detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a token, that you get from  http://192.168.0.183/M2EE/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1 , you need to add the HTTP authorization header e.g. `"Authorization: Bearer <put your token here>"` 
"" should be replaced with your token.

Comment: Can you please specify where should i declare `"Authorization: Bearer <your token>"` in my xml request

Comment: How do you send your request? What kind of utility do you use?

Comment: SOAPUI version 5.2.1

Comment: At the bottom of the request window in XML mode you should see "Headers (0)". Then proceed to that tab and add a custom header with the name "Authorization" and the value "Bearer <put your token>".
"<put your token>" should be replaced with a token.

Comment: You are awesome, thank you. can you please let me know how should i add this header if i'm sending from any other utility like third party applications?

Comment: how to add this header in xml form

Comment: I don't know what "xml form" means. I think any decent utility, that can send SOAP request should have possibility to add custom header. 

P.S. If you like the answer, please upvote and accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35338/discussion-between-prasad-maganti-and-arkadiych).